# Using Set-MpPreference to schedule Windows full and quick scans doesn't work

Tags: powershell, windows-10, task-scheduler, windows-defender

On a Windows 10 machine, I have been trying to set the time of virus scans using the following PowerShell commands.

```
Set-MpPreference -ScanParameters FullScan
Set-MpPreference -ScanScheduleDay Monday
Set-MpPreference -ScanScheduleTime (Get-Date 20:00)
Set-MpPreference -ScanOnlyIfIdleEnabled 0

Set-MpPreference -ScanScheduleQuickScanTime (Get-Date 10:00)
```

However, Windows Defender doesn't seem to obey any of my instructions. Looking on the Event Viewer > Applications and Services Logs > Microsoft > Windows > Windows Defender > Operational,
I see that Windows has been doing quick scans, but not at the time I specified. Sometimes later, sometimes earlier. Also it has not done a single full scan since I ran this script.

[image]

What's more, after running this script, it seems that my "Windows Defender Scheduled Scan" task in Task  Scheduler was deleted. I expected that the `Mp-Preference` code would modify this scheduled scan task, not delete it.

Has anyone else found that `Set-MpPreference` also doesn't work for them? Or can anyone confirm that it does work for them? If so, did you have to do anything to make it work? Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand why this question was downvoted. Was it because the code was not formatted at first? It is now.

Comment: Probably because the question is better suited for [su]. Some people rather vote down than to close for off topic questions.

Comment: I see, thanks. However, I believe that Super User is for individuals and Server Fault is for IT professionals managing many computers, and I am actually trying to use this script on many computers.

Comment: In that case, you would probably be better off to set the configuration via group policy. That would also definitely be on topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/defender/set-mppreference?view=windowsserver2022-ps) for the `Set-MpPreference` cmdlet, the `-ScanScheduleTime` parameter:

> Specifies the time of day, **as the number of minutes after midnight**, to
> perform a scheduled scan.

On my system, your input to that parameter gives:

```
PS> Get-Date 20:00

06 June 2022 20:00:00
```

It's therefore possible that schedules the run to only be on this particular day, or does something undefined. So perhaps try something like:

```
Set-MpPreference -ScanScheduleTime (New-TimeSpan -Hours 20).TotalMinutes
```

I would also point out however that the `-ScanScheduleTime` parameter only appears in the documentation for Windows Server 2022 - not in [the one for Windows 10](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/defender/set-mppreference?view=windowsserver2019-ps). Since it's not complaining of an unknown parameter it's likely still there, but that's something to keep in mind.

Comment: Thank you so much sir. Your tips helped me get it solved. ScanScheduleQuickScanTime takes a DateTime, but ScanScheduleTime takes an int, as you pointed out. And you were right, ScanScheduleTime should not be used in Windows 10, instead there is a parameter called ScanScheduleOffset that takes an int. Also I had to set RandomizeScheduleTaskTimes to $false.